# Android Emulator Does not Launch

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am struggling to get the emulator launch successfully after trying for over 2 weeks. I can really use some help with the issue or tips on troubleshooting the same.

I have been able to launch the emulator successfully on my home machine using very similar config. It fails when I connect from my work PC, I believe there is a some configuration that may be stopping this, but I have no clue what that configuration is and I don't see any error in the logs that can help me identify the issue. This is a general problem with my colleagues as well, so I am certain it's some policy or registry setting that has been set on our workstations.

If someone can help me identify the config that is stopping the launch of the emulator I can work with the IT team to make required changes.

My config is

- Android Studio 1.2.1.1
- SDK/AVD Manager v 24.3.3
- Windows 7 x64
- 16 GB RAM
- DELL E6540 Laptop | DELL Optiplex 780 desktop
- HAXM Installed
- CPU options tried: Intel x86/x86_x64 & Arm v7a
- RAM options tried: 768MB,1GB and 2GB
- Host GPU: Tried with both on and off
- Virtualization is enabled in BIOS

The Virtual Device gets created fine, but never launches successfully. I never see a window open, I have waited for more than 2 hours at several occasions.

Here are the logs of three AVDs I created

## AVD 1

Arm v7a | 768 MB RAM | Android 5.1.1 | API 22 | Host GPU Off

[image: AVD 1 | Arm v7a | 768 MB RAM | Android 5.1.1 | API 22 | Host GPU Off]

Output:

```
emulator:Found AVD name 'avd1'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator:Looking for ranchu emulator backed for arm CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator64-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator64-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Looking for emulator-arm to emulate 'arm' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-arm.exe
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: ./emulator-arm.exe
emulator:GPU emulation is disabled
emulator:Quoted param: [./emulator-arm.exe]
emulator:Quoted param: [@avd1]
emulator:Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: found SDK root at C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 22
emulator: Read property file at C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\Anon\.android\default.keyset
emulator: found magic skin width=768 height=1280 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 768MB

emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 768
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = no
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 768
  hw.lcd.height = 1280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
  À¿)pV)ußK³ªc¥ú&µß>Oí‡yù®ù×=Vš§Ùïq—#ÊÿŠÿ¿Ù&Òßué—!MáÍFåÿ¾U)›±„yþ¿ƒð—ˆ_ˆøõÊ'Ò?{’é×@zQ¿Ü•úíÈQêñ©•„yÖ/þ[â—"~ü«|ü¶,%~em.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
  avd.name = avd1
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-arm.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-arm.exe -android-hw C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP2084.tmp
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x22600000,file=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP2084.tmp,initfile=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\armeabi-v7a\/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/userdata-qemu.img,initfile=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd1.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=3
emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.801562
```

## AVD 2

Intel Atom x86 | 1536 MB RAM | Android 4.3.1 | API 18 | Use Host GPU ON

[image: AVD 2 | Intel Atom x86 | 1536 MB RAM | Android 4.3.1 | API 18 | Use Host GPU ON]

```
emulator:Found AVD name 'avd2'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for ranchu emulator backed for x86 CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator64-ranchu-x86.exe
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-ranchu-x86.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator64-ranchu-x86.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-ranchu-x86.exe
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-x86.exe
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: ./emulator-x86.exe
emulator:GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator:Quoted param: [./emulator-x86.exe]
emulator:Quoted param: [@avd2]
emulator:Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: found SDK root at C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 18
emulator: Read property file at C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\Anon\.android\default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file 'C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/tools/lib/emulator/skins/dynamic//layout'
emulator: loaded dynamic skin width=768 height=1280 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAX (version 2) is installed and usable.
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = no
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 768
  hw.lcd.height = 1280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes
  disk.ramdisk.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 281m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = avd2
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-x86.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-enable-hax"
emulator: argv[02] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[03] = "C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-x86.exe -enable-hax -android-hw C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Could not extract format of system partition!
emulator: Could not extract format of userdata partition!
emulator: Could not extract format of cache partition!
emulator: Probing system image file for partition type: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/system.img
emulator: system partition format: yaffs2
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMPA30C.tmp
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x11900000,file=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMPA30C.tmp,initfile=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-18\default\x86\/system.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 11904000

emulator: Probing userdata image file for partition type: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata.img
emulator: userdata partition format: yaffs2
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata-qemu.img,initfile=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/userdata.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: cache partition format: yaffs2
emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/cache.img
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd2.avd/cache.img
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Intel)]
emulator: OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600)]
emulator: OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.0.0 - Build 9.18.10.3220)]
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: device fd:988

emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=3
emulator:     trying to find: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.801562
```

## AVD 3

ARM | 512 MB RAM | Android 2.3.3 | API 10 | Use Host GPU OFF

[image: AVD 3 | ARM | 512 MB RAM | Android 2.3.3 | API 10 | Use Host GPU OFF]

```
emulator:Found AVD name 'avd3'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator:Looking for ranchu emulator backed for arm CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator64-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator64-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-ranchu-arm.exe
emulator:Looking for emulator-arm to emulate 'arm' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-arm.exe
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: ./emulator-arm.exe
emulator:GPU emulation is disabled
emulator:Quoted param: [./emulator-arm.exe]
emulator:Quoted param: [@avd3]
emulator:Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: found SDK root at C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 10
emulator: No build.prop property file found.
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: Cannot find target CPU architecture, defaulting to 'arm'
emulator: Cannot find target CPU ABI, defaulting to 'armeabi'
emulator: found skin 'WQVGA400' in directory: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WQVGA400
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\skins/WQVGA400/hardware.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\Anon\.android\default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file 'C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\skins/WQVGA400/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 256MB

emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
emulator: Target arch = 'arm'
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.ramSize = 256
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = yes
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 240
  hw.lcd.height = 400
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 120
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 32
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = no
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes
  disk.ramdisk.path = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = avd3
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-arm.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-arm.exe -android-hw C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: No fstab.goldfish file in ramdisk image
emulator: Probing system image file for partition type: C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/system.img
emulator: system partition format: yaffs2
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMPE615.tmp
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMPE615.tmp,initfile=C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platforms\android-10\images\/system.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: Probing userdata image file for partition type: C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: userdata partition format: yaffs2
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: cache partition format: yaffs2
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\Anon\.android\avd\avd3.avd/cache.img
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '32m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.config.low_ram' = 'true'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '120'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=3
emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
```

Comment: have you tried a non-native emulator like genymotion, or uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio?

Comment: @Viralwarrior012 Genymotion is not an option for me due to licensing constraints. I have tried installing various versions of Android Studio across various machines.

Comment: have you tried refreshing the cache, cleaning the project or restarting adb?

Comment: I think that QEMU might be the culprit here. Let me help you in another way. Since you waited 2 hours before, I am sure you have the courage to try this method. Download and install Intel INDE (inde.intel.com; it's free) and install the package. In the installation menu, make sure tick 'Install Intel HAXM'. Integrate in Android Studio/or install the version of AS and Android SDK INDE suggests. Try a Hello World app and let the built-in emulator kick in. Also in an elevated cmd, make sure HAX is on: `sc query intelhaxm`: should say RUNNING. Post feedback.

Comment: @shailenTJ I have installed Intel HAXM, `sc query intelhaxm` also tells me it is RUNNING

Comment: Can you please tell me whether you have other virtualization technology installed on your machine? For e.g: VMware or Hyper-V? Because QEMU not opening, there must be something going on. Maybe your OS Group policies are blocking virtualization, but let's find out..

Comment: @jugalThakkar are you able to create it now

Comment: I was also having the same problem, though mine by solved by installing HAXM, but still it would take hours to start the AVD. Why don't you switch to GENYMOTION emulator. It's comparatively fast; I switched to it finally. https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: @sam100rav I would love to, but genymotion is free only for personal use.

Answer (score 8):

Have you installed properly the HAXM?

I encounter same issue before, before learning that
**HAXM is not yet enabled** after downloading it in android sdk manager.
[image]

You need some steps to follow to fully get the best experience out of the Android* emulator using the Intel HAXM driver.

Prerequisites

Intel HAXM requires the Android* SDK to be installed (version 17 or higher). For more information, refer to the Android* developer website (http://developer.android.com/sdk/).

```
System Requirements

Hardware Requirements:

Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
At least 1 GB of available RAM
Supported Operating Systems:

Microsoft Windows* 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit)
Microsoft Windows* 7 (32/64-bit)
Microsoft Windows Vista* (32/64-bit)
Important: Intel HAXM cannot be used on systems without an Intel processor, or with an Intel processor that lacks the hardware features described in the "Hardware Requirements" section above.
To determine the capabilities of your Intel processor, visit http://ark.intel.com/
Additionally, Intel HAXM can be used only with Android* x86 emulator images provided by Intel. 
Intel HAXM cannot be used with ARM* Android* emulator images or non-Intel x86 Android* emulator images.
```

1. Under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to get it installed.

2.Extract the installer inside the "extras" directory and follow the installation instructions for your platform.

[image]

Installing Intel® HAXM on Windows*

Warning: Intel HAXM installation will fail if your system does not meet the system requirements, including support for Intel processor features, such as Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel VT).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After all the steps it will work properly.
[image]

hope it helps...
heres [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Comment: Yes HAXM Is installed, and I do get the same message "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode" also sc query intelhaxm reports it to be in RUNNING state

Comment: Have you installed Intel x86 Atom System Image in each version of api you are using? please check it.

Comment: Cristiana214, yes I have. I believe its some policy on the OS, I don't know how to figure out what policy that is. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

One idea that you might want to try is to create an AVD for an old version of Android (such as 2.1 or 2.2).  In my experience those versions start reasonable fast even under emulation.  It may not be useful for creating projects, but should help you determine if the emulator is working in general.

Comment: I have tried older versions of Android as well. Added to OP

Comment: Rats - I was hoping it was merely slow instead of simply not working.  The only other idea is when you start the AVD, Android Studio displays some messages, and maybe there is something there that might help.

Comment: those messages are from the emulator logs that are in the OP

Answer (score 2):

Wipe the data in the folders `C:\Users\<username>\.android\ avd and cache` Then start Creating AVD from scratch through [image]

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, does not help. I have tried creating AVD from scratch on various different machines too

Answer (score 2):

I am using `API 22 : Android 5.1.1` . I was facing the same issue then I downloaded the latest **system image** from android sdk manager to run Nexus 5 emulator.

The System-Image was

**Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image**

and then selected this system image while creating a Virtual Device in Android Virtual Device Manager. Just make sure that you have checked the **store a snapshot** checkbox . Now run your emulator.

You need to decide which emulator you want to use and select its system image according to it. For eg. Nexus 5 has an arm processor (like that). 
You should also download all the system images for your emulators.
[image]

Comment: I have everything except *Wear* images installed

Answer (score 2):

You could try these :

1) The skin is set to `WVGA800` by default try changing it to `HVGA`.

2) Sometimes it is the problem with the `graphic card and drivers`(though you mentioned you tried this on different system, but check if the drivers are same?)

3) Sometimes the issue maybe because of `screen size` of emulator. Try changing `lcd.height, lcd.width, skin.name, skin.path` in the config files

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to set the Android emulator in SDK manager to the last one available (29.2.1).

[image]