# Jenkins Android Emulator error: device 'localhost:7903' not found (the emulator starts but the connection to it fails)

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

I have installed Jenkins with Android Emulator Plugin on my MacMini. But emulator does not work:

Here is the log:

```
[android] Starting Android emulator
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/tools/emulator -ports 7903,7904 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window -verbose
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 51200 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

emulator: found SDK root at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 19
emulator: Read property file at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'HVGA' in directory: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/skins/HVGA/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

emulator: autoconfig: -snapstorage /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/snapshots.img
emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes

  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 320
  hw.lcd.height = 480
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes
  disk.ramdisk.path = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  disk.snapStorage.path = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/snapshots.img
  avd.name = hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/tools/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-boot-property"
emulator: argv[02] = "persist.sys.language=en"
emulator: argv[03] = "-boot-property"
emulator: argv[04] = "persist.sys.country=US"
emulator: argv[05] = "-android-ports"
emulator: argv[06] = "7903,7904"
emulator: argv[07] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[08] = "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/tools/emulator64-arm -boot-property persist.sys.language=en -boot-property persist.sys.country=US -android-ports 7903,7904 -android-hw /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator:     trying to find: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/tools/lib/ca-bundle.pem

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.language' = 'en'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.country' = 'US'
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-jenkins/emulator-dyB0c4
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x22600000,file=/tmp/android-jenkins/emulator-dyB0c4,initfile=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/system-images/android-19/default/armeabi-v7a//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 209715200
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 6400
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 51200
    Block groups: 2
    Reserved block group size: 15
Created filesystem with 11/12800 inodes and 1865/51200 blocks
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata-qemu.img,initfile=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Champion/workspace/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_HVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_jenkins.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.config.low_ram' = 'true'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:7904' to ADB server
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: Failed to parse AndroidStudio preferences file usage.statistics.xml
emulator: Defaulting user crash-report opt-in to false
emulator: Skipping metrics reporting: No user opt-in.
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:170: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:7904
unable to connect to localhost:7904: Connection refused
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:7904 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:7904' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:7904
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:7904 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:7904' not found
```

I have tried different emulators (API level 15,16,17,18,19,20). I have also tried different Android Emulator Plugin-Versions (2.13.1 and 2.10). Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Emulator Does not Launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272348/android-emulator-does-not-launch)

Comment: Hi Wilder Pereira. The topic "Android Emulator Does not Launch" don't contains any answer that could help me. In my case the emulator starts but the connection to the emulator does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. In my case the solution was to downgrade android emulator plugin to version 2.12. The latest version (2.13.1) did not work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

`Android emulator plugin` in `Jenkins` isn't very stable (might be the plugin problem or my `Jenkins` build machine). I've found one configuration which works for me all the time.

This is the line from logs (compare with yours):
`$/backup/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -ports 7379,7380 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WXGA800_android-17_x86_namshi -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -no-boot-anim -noaudio -verbose`

And here how the emulator configuration from the job looks:

[image: emulator config]

My advise is to play with different configurations and find the one stable. Also, if ports are busy, try to reboot your `Jenkins` machine and see if it helps.